# ASP.NET AJAX's Combobox - Cannot Programatically Change the Selected Item

Tags: asp.net-ajax

I'm using the new Microsoft ASP.NET Ajax ComboBox control in my web application, and I'm having trouble figuring out how to programmatically set the selected list item. For example, I have a form to accept addresses and a ComboBox to accept a city name. After the user enters and saves and address, I'd like to reset the form, including the ComboBoxes.

With a regular ASP.NET dropdownlist control I can reset the selected item like below:

```
City.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

The ASP.NET AJAX ComboBox control accepts this line of code; but when the page posts back, the previously selected value is still selected. Help would be appreciated.

Update: I tried the following to no avail...

```
City.ClearSelection();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One Solution for this is use Following 2 Commands Before you load page Second time or make it visible in update Panel

```
            Combobox1.ClearSelection()
            Combobox1.Dispose()
```

This will Clear Combobox Value.

Hope this Helps. Took me a while to find it.

Answer (score 1):

This is an open issue on CodePlex. So, because it's a bug, there's no solution until a patch is issued. Here's the [issue](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/WorkItem/View.aspx?WorkItemId=22451) on CodePlex.

Answer (score 1):

it's work when I use DropDownStyle="DropDown"
and this command to clear text
combobox1.SelectedItem.Text = ""

Answer (score 1):

*** This is still a bug as of 2-18-2011 Version 3.5.40412.2 of the toolkit ***

For the sake of all the Google searchers out there, none of the fixes I found for this problem worked (including the various ones involving iterating through the controls collection to find the hidden control, Dispose, etc.)

*** This works for me, no matter how many layers deep I have the combobox buried in other controls/panels etc***

combobox.Items.Clear();

((TextBox)cmbMachineNum.FindControl("TextBox")).Text = "";

Comment: Thanks a bunch, @Paul. This was driving me nuts all day... :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ComboBox.Text = "";  
ComboBox.ClearSelection();
```

Comment: Just tried that and no luck. Previously selected value is still there. Only solution is to re-bind the list, but I'm trying to avoid another database hit.

Comment: It there an items collection with a clear method? ComboBox.Items.Clear()?

Comment: Yes, and that does clear the list items, BUT the selected value STILL displays in the box.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to the CascadingDropDown? If so, set the SelectedValue of the CascadingDropDown to null.

```
CascadingDropDown1.SelectedValue = null;
```

Comment: Tim, actually I'm talking about the new MS Ajax Control Toolkit's ComboBox control. Unfortunately, setting the .SelectedValue property of the control to null still doesn't work. Convinced at this point this is a bug in the control. Wish MS would confirm it, though.

Answer (score 0):

ok so if you want to set the index it is actually stored in the hidden field in the control it looks like.  So what i am doing to clear it is this.

```
foreach (Control control in cbFeatures.Controls)
            {
                if (control is HiddenField)
                    ((HiddenField)control).Value = "0";
            }
```

This is working great for me where the value is the index that you want to set.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by clearing the hidden fields as explained in the following blog http://techiecentre.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 0):

Replace `City.ClearSelection()` with the following:

```
City.Items.Insert(0, "");
City.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Now this will put an empty string in the drop down list part of the City control as well as setting the text to empty string. To remove the empty string from the drop down list use

```
City.Items.Remove("");
```

in the City `Page_Load` event.